# AngularJS $httpProvider undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'am trying to use a basic sample of interceptors, so I stared with a little piece of code but without success:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).
  config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$location) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {templateUrl: 'home.html',   controller: homeCtrl}).
    when('/login', {templateUrl: 'login.html',   controller: loginController}).
    otherwise({redirectTo : '/home' });
}]);


app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

When I launch my index page I have an error message in the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined from app
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Check your angularjs version and corresponding version of $http documentation. The issue may with the version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is perfect. You need to make sure you are using the correct version of angularjs. The $http.interceptors array was added in version 1.1.4.

I made a plunker with your example working with angular 1.1.4, check it out here http://plnkr.co/edit/cuPfat?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

`$httpProvider.interceptors` array was added in AngularJS v.1.1.4 (I believe). You're most probably using some older version of AngularJS.

Btw, that error says `$httpProvider.interceptors` is not defined, not `$httpProvider` as your title implies.