# Can not push an interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

In angular js i have made a service that should authenticate user simply it stores a token and send it with every request so i used interceptors.
her is the code of the interceptor.

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService',['$q', '$location', '$cookieStore', function( $q, $location, $cookieStore){
     var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};
     var _request = function(config){
         config.headers = config.headers || {};
         var authData = $cookieStore.get('AuthorizationHeader');
         if(authData){
             config.headers.AuthorizationHeade = authData.token;
         }
         return config;
     }

     var _responseError = function(rejection) {
         if(rejection.status === 401){
             $location.path('/');
         }
         return $q.reject(rejection);
     }
     authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
     authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;
     return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

the problem is when i try to add the interceptor with

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
});
```

i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined from AccApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message You mentioned suggests that `$httpProvider` parameter may not be injected properly. Maybe You use some kind of obfuscation that changes the variable name and breaks the injection mechanism. 
Please try to change:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) { ... });
```

into:

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) { ... }]);
```

Let me know if this solves the issue.

**Edit**

After a short discussion in the comments, it seems that the error was caused by too old AngularJS version. In order to use the `interceptors` collection at least 1.1.4 version is required, according to this link: [AngularJS $httpProvider undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364450/angularjs-httpprovider-undefined).

**Edit II**

After upgrading the version of angularjs the issue was resolved, but another issue appeared and it seems that You solved it by yourself :). As agreed, I'm adding information about it to the answer.
According to our discussion, `ngRoute` has to be included after upgrading angularjs version, although the code worked without it in version *1.0.7*.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Please put a breakpoint in the line when you call the `push` function and check properties of the `$httpProvider` parameter. Please also make sure that the code registering the factory is called before You try to add it as an interceptor. This may be obvious, but is worth checking.

Comment: $get: Array[7]
0: "$httpBackend"
1: "$browser"
2: "$cacheFactory"
3: "$rootScope"
4: "$q"
5: "$injector"

Comment: interceptors is undifiend

Comment: So please verify angularjs version You are using. This link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364450/angularjs-httpprovider-undefined suggests that at least 1.1.4 version is required.

Comment: i am using 1.0.7 i will check that

Comment: after updating version now i get Uncaught object

Comment: But is the error thrown from the same place in the code? Please provide more information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56674/discussion-between-lukasz-m-and-user2918388).

Comment: @LukaszM can we chat on similar issue ?

Comment: If Your issue is different, I suppose You should rather describe Your problem as a new question, so more people can try to help.